# Selecting all not present in the intermediate table with ought nested select

Tags: mysql, select, many-to-many

I have 2 tables t1 and t2 and an intermediate table t2_has_t1 linking those two tables (many to many).

I want to select all from t1 that are not linked to t2 (via t2_has_t1). I can do it with nested select but I was wondering if this can be done in a more efficient way

This fiddle shows how I do it with nested select.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fb9d81/2/0
(fiddle updated)

Comment: SELECT * FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t2_has_t1
ON t1.id_t1 = t2_has_t1.fk_t1
WHERE t2_has_t1.fk_t2 IS NULL;

fixing the on statement on duelisy's answer it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do it in a single query, you can use a join, something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t2_has_t1
ON t1.id_t1 = t2_has_t1.fk_t2
WHERE t2_has_t1.fk_t2 IS NULL
```

Comment: damn, you're totally right! Had the gut feeling it's very simple!! It still is early in the morning here :) . Thanks dude!

Comment: damn twice, doesn't work! Just noticed the on statement you have so added another pair of values to the intermediate table and... does not work. Updated the fiddle ( http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fb9d81/2/0 )

Comment: mate, please fix the relation link (on) in your solution otherwise it's almost correct ;)